# R Identifying pairs in irregular dataset

Tags: arrays, r, match

I need to identify pairs of arrivals and departures. The `movement` variable identifies `ARR` and `DEP` but sometimes among `ARR`-`DEP` pairs there are other rows that mess things up. I would like to keep `ARR`-`DEP` pairs and discard the rest.

Data looks mostly like this:

```
  id    time            movement    origin  dest
   1    10/06/2011 15:54    ARR        15    15
   1    10/06/2011 16:14    DEP        15    29
   2    10/06/2011 17:59    ARR        73    73
   2    10/06/2011 18:10    DEP        73    75
   2    10/06/2011 21:10    ARR        75    75
   2    10/06/2011 21:20    DEP        75    73
```

If you load the data below, you will see "misbehaved" cases at `id` Id5: Standalone movement without pair to match. Id 6: Extra `DEP` record (that I would discard) and Id 8: `DEP` first instead of `ARR`.

I have tried the following:

```
dfru$test <- FALSE
dfru$test[which(dfru$movement == "ARR")] <- TRUE
```

`dfru$test[which(dfru$test[-1] =="TRUE")] <- 1` #Doesn't work (i.e. assigns TRUE or 1 to `id` 5 and not to the last record of `id`4.

If I change the last line for `dfru$test[which(dfru$test[-1] =="TRUE" & dfru$movement == "DEP")] <- 1` it doesn't work either to match trips.

Any ideas? Commands/packages that I could use?

Data:

```
dfru <- structure(list(time = structure(c(7L, 16L, 8L, 11L, 18L, 20L, 
10L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 15L, 19L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 17L
), .Label = c("10/06/2011 09:08", "10/06/2011 10:54", "10/06/2011 11:38", 
"10/06/2011 12:41", "10/06/2011 12:54", "10/06/2011 14:26", "10/06/2011 14:33", 
"10/06/2011 14:59", "10/06/2011 17:12", "10/06/2011 17:14", "10/06/2011 17:23", 
"10/06/2011 18:56", "10/06/2011 19:03", "10/06/2011 19:04", "10/06/2011 19:16", 
"10/06/2011 19:24", "10/06/2011 20:12", "10/06/2011 21:10", "10/06/2011 22:28", 
"10/06/2011 23:40"), class = "factor"), movement = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("ARR", "DEP", "ITZ"), class = "factor"), 
    origin = c(15L, 15L, 73L, 73L, 75L, 75L, 17L, 17L, 49L, 49L, 
    15L, 15L, 32L, 10L, 10L, 17L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L), dest = c(15L, 
    29L, 73L, 75L, 75L, 73L, 17L, 48L, 49L, 15L, 15L, 49L, 32L, 
    10L, 17L, 10L, 76L, 65L, 76L, 65L), id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
    8L)), .Names = c("time", "movement", "origin", "dest", "id"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: What algorithm have you tried, and what is the programming question?  As posted, the question is similar to here is some data, and goal, what algorithm will apply?  That's not a programming question.

Comment: The programming question is how to subset the dataset to contain only pairs. I considered `for loop` but it is too slow for the dataset Im handling. I also considered the `which` function unsuccessfully. Im new to R so maybe someone may have any other idea in mind.

Comment: @John do you have any idea of any algorithm/package/etc that could be applicable to this case?

Comment: I'm still not clear on the question.  Is this the algorithm you are trying to implement?  a) for each id, b) for each ARR list dest, c) Is there a DEP where origin is in list of dest.

Comment: @John For each id, and for each ARR within that id, take the ARR row and the next DEP row. Discard all the rest.

Comment: @user3507584  Could you check if this helps `dfru[dfru[, V1:= rep(c('ARR', 'DEP'), length.out=.N), by=id][, movement==V1,by=list(cumsum(V1=='ARR'), id)]$V1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I define some helper functions to get the job done

```
gapply<-function(x, y, f) unsplit(lapply(split(x, y), f), y)
markpair<-function(x) {
    arr <- cumsum(x$movement=="ARR")
    dep <- gapply(x$movement, arr, function(x) x=="DEP" & cumsum(x=="DEP")==1)
    dep <- dep $ (arr<0)
    hasdep <- gapply(dep, arr, any) 
    arr <- x$movement=="ARR" & hasdep
    cbind(x, keep = dep | arr)
}
gapply(dfru, dfru$id, markpair)
```

which returns

```
               time movement origin dest id  keep
1  10/06/2011 14:33      ARR     15   15  1  TRUE
2  10/06/2011 19:24      DEP     15   29  1  TRUE
3  10/06/2011 14:59      ARR     73   73  2  TRUE
4  10/06/2011 17:23      DEP     73   75  2  TRUE
5  10/06/2011 21:10      ARR     75   75  2  TRUE
6  10/06/2011 23:40      DEP     75   73  2  TRUE
7  10/06/2011 17:14      ARR     17   17  3  TRUE
8  10/06/2011 18:56      DEP     17   48  3  TRUE
9  10/06/2011 11:38      ARR     49   49  4  TRUE
10 10/06/2011 14:26      DEP     49   15  4  TRUE
11 10/06/2011 19:16      ARR     15   15  4  TRUE
12 10/06/2011 22:28      DEP     15   49  4  TRUE
13 10/06/2011 17:12      ITZ     32   32  5 FALSE
14 10/06/2011 12:41      ARR     10   10  6  TRUE
15 10/06/2011 12:54      DEP     10   17  6  TRUE
16 10/06/2011 19:04      DEP     17   10  6 FALSE
17 10/06/2011 09:08      ARR     76   76  7  TRUE
18 10/06/2011 10:54      DEP     76   65  7  TRUE
19 10/06/2011 19:03      DEP     76   76  8 FALSE
20 10/06/2011 20:12      ITZ     76   65  8 FALSE
```

which seems to mark the bad rows based on your description

Answer (score 2):

This produces the desired result in your question and may be a bit simpler.

```
library(data.table)
codes <- c(ARR=1,DEP=-1,ITZ=0)
dfru[,keep:=ifelse(abs(c(2,diff(codes[movement])))==2,TRUE,FALSE),by=id]
dfru[!(movement %in% c("ARR","DEP")),keep:=FALSE]
# result <- dfru[(keep)]  # remove rows flagged for deletion...
dfru
#                 time movement origin dest id  keep
#  1: 10/06/2011 14:33      ARR     15   15  1  TRUE
#  2: 10/06/2011 19:24      DEP     15   29  1  TRUE
#  3: 10/06/2011 14:59      ARR     73   73  2  TRUE
#  4: 10/06/2011 17:23      DEP     73   75  2  TRUE
#  5: 10/06/2011 21:10      ARR     75   75  2  TRUE
#  6: 10/06/2011 23:40      DEP     75   73  2  TRUE
#  7: 10/06/2011 17:14      ARR     17   17  3  TRUE
#  8: 10/06/2011 18:56      DEP     17   48  3  TRUE
#  9: 10/06/2011 11:38      ARR     49   49  4  TRUE
# 10: 10/06/2011 14:26      DEP     49   15  4  TRUE
# 11: 10/06/2011 19:16      ARR     15   15  4  TRUE
# 12: 10/06/2011 22:28      DEP     15   49  4  TRUE
# 13: 10/06/2011 17:12      ITZ     32   32  5 FALSE
# 14: 10/06/2011 12:41      ARR     10   10  6  TRUE
# 15: 10/06/2011 12:54      DEP     10   17  6  TRUE
# 16: 10/06/2011 19:04      DEP     17   10  6 FALSE
# 17: 10/06/2011 09:08      ARR     76   76  7  TRUE
# 18: 10/06/2011 10:54      DEP     76   65  7  TRUE
# 19: 10/06/2011 19:03      DEP     76   76  8  TRUE
# 20: 10/06/2011 20:12      ITZ     76   65  8 FALSE
```

This approach uses `diff(...)` on coded movement (ARR=1, DEP=-1, ITZ=0) to produce a vector that will be either 2 or -2 if ARR is followed by DEP. If there is an extra DEP that element will be 0 and should be flagged for deletion. Then we flag any element that is not ARR or DEP for deletion. Then, optionally, we delete the flagged rows.

Your question is still a bit vague as there are many possibilities, in principle, not accounted for. For instance, what should be done if an `id` sequence starts with DEP? What if there is a ARR only (no DEPs)?

Comment: Thanks @jlhoward, in case of a sequence starting with DEP I would delete it too. As far as I have seen, there are no ARR only. If they were, I would delete them too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at the answer.  If it doesn't answer the question, hopefully it provides an approach to get to the answer you are looking for.
The algorithm is to 
  1) split dfru by id.
  2) For each id, 
  2a) determine the arr and dep rows.
  2b) Find the match between arr$dest and dep$origin.
  2c) Return a list containing the matching dep and arr

```
forEachID<- function(id) {
  # print(id)  
  id_arr <- which(id$movement=='ARR')
  id_dep <- which(id$movement=='DEP')
  arr_dest <- id[id_arr,'dest']
  dep_origin <- id[id_dep,'origin']
  # print(arr_dest)
  # print(dep_origin)
  m<-match(arr_dest, dep_origin)
  # print(m)
  tMatch<-NULL
  if (length(m)>0) {
    arr <- id[id_arr[m],]
    dep <- id[id_dep[m],]
    tMatch<-list(arr=arr, dep=dep)
  }
}
paths <- by(dfru,dfru$id,forEachID)
print(paths)
```

Based on the comment, here's an updated answer to match based on time sequence

```
matchByDestOrigin <- function(id,id_arr,id_dep) {
  m<-match(arr_dest, dep_origin)
  tMatch<-NULL  
  if (length(m)>0) {
    arr <- id[id_arr[m],]
    dep <- id[id_dep[m],]
    tMatch<-list(arr=arr, dep=dep)
  }
}
matchByDestOrigin <- function(id,id_arr,id_dep) {
  tarr <- id[id_arr,]
  tarr <- tarr[order(tarr$time),]
  tdep <- id[id_dep,]
  tdep <- tdep[order(tdep$time),]
  nrows <- min(nrow(tarr),nrow(tdep))
  tMatch <- NULL
  if (nrows>0) {
    arr <- tarr[nrows,]
    dep <- tdep[nrows,]
    tMatch<-list(arr=arr, dep=dep)
  }
}


forEachIDMatchSequence<- function(id) {
  # print(id)  
  id_arr <- which(id$movement=='ARR')
  id_dep <- which(id$movement=='DEP')
  return(matchByDestOrigin(id,id_arr,id_dep))
}
forEachIDMatchDestOrigin<- function(id) {
  # print(id)  
  id_arr <- which(id$movement=='ARR')
  id_dep <- which(id$movement=='DEP')
  return(matchByTimeSequence(id,id_arr,id_dep))
}
destOriginPaths <- by(dfru,dfru$id,forEachIDMatchDestOrigin)
print(destOriginPaths)
seqPaths <- by(dfru,dfru$id,forEachIDMatchSequence)
print(seqPaths)
```

Comment: I will try to implement this. Thanks @John

Comment: R is optimized for vector operations, so it doesn't work well with scalar "for loops".  You should try to use one of the apply, by, or ply functions instead of loops.

Comment: I'm new to R also.  If you wait for some more answers, they will probably be better answers...